# Why a data grid view is not being updated based on data set connected with bindig source?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I have a `dataGridView` control with data source set at `dataTableDocumentsBindingSource`

[image]

The `dataGridView` is not being updated when i am updating `dataSet1` with the following code:

```
    DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
    /.../
     DataTable documentsTable = ds.Tables["DataTableDocuments"];
                        DataRow workRow = documentsTable.NewRow();
                        workRow["id"] = Int32.Parse(item.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText);
                        workRow["Title"] = item.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText;
                        documentsTable.Rows.Add(workRow);
    /.../
return ds;
```

**How to get dataGridView to update when respective dataSet is being updated?**

I have been already trying `dataGridView.Refresh()` and `dataGridView.Update()` but neither works.

Comment: Have you tried source.ResetBindings(false);  ?

Comment: Yes unluckily it does not work either.

Comment: in your above method you are creating a new data set each time you call this method and i think you need to set BindingSource.DataSet = returnedDataSet each time and after that you need to call BindingSource.ResetBindings(false);

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz: This worked out. Could you please advice how no to create a new data set each time but rather refer to existing dataSet? Do I correctly assume that a data set is stored somewhere in a memory and I may load it from there as I would load data from database? How do I "connect" to a dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could do it like this

```
public class Xyz
{
    DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
    /.../

     private void UpdateData()
     {
        DataTable documentsTable = ds.Tables["DataTableDocuments"];
        DataRow workRow = documentsTable.NewRow();
        workRow["id"] = Int32.Parse(item.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText);
        workRow["Title"] = item.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText;
        documentsTable.Rows.Add(workRow);

        yourbindingsource.ResetBindings(false);
      }
}
```